# Jena 3.2.0 tdbload2 riotException: Failed to determine the content type

Tags: jena

I used **tdbload2** (in jena3.2.0) to build database from **freebase-rdf-latest**.

An error occured,

[cc@localhost dir]$ ../apache-jena-3.2.0/bin/tdbloader2  --loc=./d-freebase/   ./freebase-rdf-latest

21:33:22 INFO -- TDB Bulk Loader Start

21:33:22 INFO Data Load Phase

21:33:22 INFO Got 1 data files to load

21:33:22 INFO Data file 1: freebase-rdf-latest

INFO  Load: freebase-rdf-latest -- 2017/04/06 21:33:23 CST

org.apache.jena.riot.**RiotException**: Failed to determine the content type: (URI=freebase-rdf-latest : stream=null)

```
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:854)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:667)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:637)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:626)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:617)
at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.bulkloader2.ProcNodeTableBuilder.exec(ProcNodeTableBuilder.java:78)
at tdb.bulkloader2.CmdNodeTableBuilder.exec(CmdNodeTableBuilder.java:113)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
at tdb.bulkloader2.CmdNodeTableBuilder.main(CmdNodeTableBuilder.java:61)
```

21:33:23 ERROR Failed during data phase

---

But when I used tdbload2 in *jena 2.12.1*, no error occured!

So, I wonder why RiotException was raised when I used tdbload2 in jena 3.2.0?

---

The format of freebase-rdf-latest,

```html
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/american_football.football_player.footballdb_id>    <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.property>      .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/american_football.football_player.footballdb_id>    <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.name>   "footballdb ID"@en      .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/american_football.football_player.footballdb_id>    <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.property.unique>       "true"  .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Jena version 2.12.1, but I've found with Jena version 3.2.0, I need to specify the content type using the file extension.

Try renaming your input file from "./freebase-rdf-latest" to "./freebase-rdf-latest.nt".

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Jena).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    I‘ve got new warnings. How can i config this process? I mean if there is a configure file where i can set the input file format, the log format, etc.

Comment: @WuLee if tdbloader2 sees a "log4j.properties" file in your current working directory, it'll use it (which should eliminate those warnings). You can copy an example from `$JENA_HOME/jena-log4j.properties`. Just make sure to name it "log4j.properties". I'm not sure if it is possible to specify the input file format using a configuration file however.